# Problems sending data via MPI_Bcast

Tags: c, mpi

I defined the point structure with MPI_Type_contiguous. After doing this, I initialize my type and subsequently I want to send the centroids and have them printed by the other processes which are different from the root process. I wrote this code, sending the centroids via MPI_Bcast but when I try to print the centroids inside the for loop it gives me a series of errors:

```
[rob: 10463] *** Process received signal ***
[rob: 10463] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[rob: 10463] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[rob: 10463] Failing at address: 0x1000

Primary job terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. For user-direction, the job has been aborted.

mpirun noticed that process rank 2 with PID 0 on node rob exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Where do I go wrong?

```
typedef struct {
double x;
double y;
} Point;

void initialize(Point *centroids, int num_clusters) {
int dex;
srand(time(NULL));
for (dex = 0; dex < num_clusters; dex++) {
    centroids[dex].x = ((double) (rand() % 1000)) / 1000;
    centroids[dex].y = ((double) (2 * rand() % 1000)) / 1000;
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank, size;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

MPI_Datatype POINT;
MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_DOUBLE, &POINT);
MPI_Type_commit(&POINT);

int num_clusters = 0;
Point* centroids;

if (rank == 0) {
    num_clusters = 2;
    centroids = calloc(sizeof(Point), num_clusters);
    initialize(centroids, num_clusters);
}

MPI_Bcast(centroids, 2, POINT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (rank != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_clusters; i++) {
        printf("Centroid X: %f\n", centroids[i].x);
        printf("Centroid Y: %f\n", centroids[i].y);
    }
}

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to allocate `centroids` on **all** ranks

Comment: in addition to the lack of allocation for `centroids` on all rank as already noticed, you should also choose another name for your derived type. Indeed, names starting with `MPI_` are reserved for the MPI library so you are not allowed (well, you take risks) to define this `MPI_POINT`

Comment: Ok thanks, I changed `MPI_POINT` to `POINT`. But I didn't understand how to allocate `centroids` to the other ranks.

Comment: `calloc(...)` on all ranks, `initialize(...)` only on rank `0`.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Could you just post that piece of code? I would be grateful, I'm a beginner with MPI and I still can't quite understand how it all works.